# how to make edittext field for decimals

Tags: android

how to make dynamically edittext field for accepting only double and float values?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use this method in your Activity:

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text01);
et.setInputType(0x00002002);
```

or

```
EditText et = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.text01) ;
et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

here `text01` is id of `EditText` field in your `R.java` file;

Reference:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android:inputType

Comment: It would be better style to write : setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL); which is the same value, but clearer for the reader

Comment: -1 use of magic numbers, and assumption that it is an activity (could be a viewgroup)

Answer (score 4):

Maybe a nicer solution would be using

```
    et.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER 
                         | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);
```

**Edit:** I have also added the flag `InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL` to accept dobules too.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `setInputType(int type)` function:

```
EditText e
e.setInputType(InputType.Number) //Many other options are also available
```

Answer (score 0):

**et.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_FLAG_DECIMAL);**

where **setRawInputType** it corresponds to the **android:inputType** attribute.